# Spring MVC in conjunction with angular vanishing view

Tags: java, spring

I try connect SpringMVC, apache tiles, angular and boostrap. After typing: `http://localhost:8080/testrest` menu appears with Bootstrap, the table in which they appear videos and does not pass even a second it gets a white screen.

Check my video here: https://youtu.be/V9FvL0yUWXU

Rest returns the data, so it's ok.

Code AngularJs:
https://github.com/giecmarcin/[...]/main/webapp/WEB-INF/static/js

View file:
https://github.com/giecmarcin/[...]B-INF/pages/MovieManagment.jsp

RestController:

```
package com.springapp.mvc.controller;

import com.springapp.mvc.entities.Movie;
import com.springapp.mvc.services.MovieService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Marcin on 19.04.2016.
 */

@RestController
public class MovieRestController {

    @Autowired
    MovieService movieService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/movies/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> listAllMovies() {
        List<Movie> movies = movieService.findAll();
        if(movies.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movies, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

Kontroler zwracający widok
@Controller
public class IndexController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/testrest")
    public String getTest(){
        return "MovieManagment";
    }
}
```

Thank you for help.